# Spring Java - Possible to add query string to Redirect ModelAndView?

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to implement an external ModelAndView redirect from my Spring controller.  However, whenever I try to add a query string to the URL, it appends a `/` to the end of the URL before the query string.  So even if I set up my string to be:

```
return new ModelAndView("redirect:https://www.google.com?test=101")
```

It will show in my network traffic that I am trying to access `https://www.google.com/?test=101`. Should I be using ModelAndView?

Answer (score 1):

It is dead simple, return a string.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String redirectToFoo() {
    return "https://www.google.com?test=101";
}
```

> Should I be using ModelAndView?

Since you return an external URL, no internal Model or View is necessary any more. You shouldn't use `ModelAndView`.